# How can Order Many-to-Many with Ordered relationships

Tags: core-data, relationship

Ordered relationships works great... but i have not found documentation about how can use the check "ordered" in the fetch controller.

My problem is: How i can sort the fetchcontroller? What's the key (SORT_VALUE) to use in `-sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:`

eg:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortPlaylistSongs = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"SORT_VALUE" ascending:YES];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set sort descriptors to fetch request in the following way:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[sortPlaylistSongs]];
```

SORT_VALUE - generally is the property name. In case with Core Data it's attribute name.